# Is there any human female spouse that won't disappear?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I've tried to get married in skyrim but after the wedding the wife disappears. Is there any female human spouses that WON'T disappear after getting married? If so who?  Also I play on Xbox 360 if that helps. And does getting the legendary edition of the game fix this glitch? I'm sick of using up gold just to see this glitch happen.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, and I doubt that it’s specific to particular spouses.

Comment: Could you give more details about what happens?

Comment: I request this wife to move into my house in whiterun before she leaves the chapel. Then I fast travel there and she's not there. Could it be that she actually walks all the way there or is it a glitch?

Comment: I don’t know. What if you wait 24 hours (in-game)? Does she show up? Maybe walk outside the city and then come back in and check in your house again.

Answer (score 0):

They will simply go to their regular home. Like for example Ysolda will go to her tiny house in Whiterun behind the markets. Then once you find your spouse ask them to move to your new home.

Answer (score -1):

They don't disappear if you talk to them in the chapel and tell them where you want to live.

Comment: This isn't true. They disappear even if you talked to them